# Lisp recursive macro problems

Tags: recursion, macros, lisp, common-lisp

I'm writing a recursive Lisp macro taking a number *n* and evaluating the body *n* times (an exercise from ANSI Lisp). I've tried two ways of doing this -- having the macro call itself in its expansion, and having the macro expand into a local recursive function. Neither works as I want it to.

Here's the first one -- it has a stack overflow, but when I look at its expansion using macroexpand-1 it seems fine to me.

```
(defmacro n-times (n &rest body)
  (let ((i (gensym)))
    `(let ((,i ,n))
     (if (zerop ,i) nil
         (progn
           ,@body
           (n-times (- ,i 1) ,@body))))))
```

Here's the second one -- it makes an error, "undefined function #xxxx called with arguments (z)" where #xxxx is the name of the gensym and z is 1 less than the number I call it with. I think there's a problem with the way I use gensyms and flet together, but I'm not sure how to do this correctly.

```
(defmacro n-times (n &rest body)
  (let ((g (gensym)))
    `(flet ((,g (x)
              (if (zerop x) nil
                  (progn
                    ,@body
                    (,g (- x 1))))))
       (,g ,n))))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer your first question, you have a recursive macro expansion that never stops recursing. The presence of the `if` doesn't stop the recursive macro expansion, since macro expansion happens at compile-time and your `if` happens at run-time.

To answer your second question, you can't use `flet` to specify recursive functions, you have to use `labels` instead.

Comment: Thanks, that made it work! Why can't you use flet to specify recursive functions?

Comment: `flet` makes the bindings visible inside the body only. `labels` makes the bindings visible inside the binding definitions as well.

Comment: Got it. Would the first method be OK if I took the `if` out of the backquote to test `(zerop n)` at compile-time?

Comment: @lightlike Yes---that's basically what Rainer's answer is---but like Rainer said, your macro argument must be a number literal, and not some expression like `n` or `(+ 3 4)` (which the macro will see as a symbol and a list, respectively; remember macros are expanded at compile-time and expressions are evaluated at run-time).

Answer (score 7):

Since macro expansion in Common Lisp happens kind of before runtime, this is slightly tricky.

Remember, the macro sees source code. This means:

- the number n must be passed as a number, not a variable, when you use the macro. Thus at macro expansion time the number is known. For such a macro, I would check that in the macro - otherwise you always be tempted to write something like `(let ((n 10)) (n-times n ...))` - which won't work.
- the macro needs to compute the recursive iteration. Thus the logic is in the macro, and not in the generated code. Each macro needs to generate code, which is one step simpler at macro expansion time - until the basic case is reached.

Comment: OK, thank you. Why isn't it OK to call a macro that's supposed to take a number with a variable containing the number? Also, is the first method (having the macro call itself in its expansion) 'wrong' compared to the second method (having the macro expand into the recursive function)?

Comment: There's a nice section in Let Over Lambda that covers Rainer's points in this post in more detail: http://letoverlambda.com/index.cl/guest/chap5.html#sec_5